# Flatten long nesting of Monadic types in Scala

Tags: scala, monads

I have a function to get a seq of workItemIds given JobIds, with following signature -

```
def getWorkItemIds(jobId: JobId): Future[Seq[WorkItemId]]
```

I have another function which given a WorkItemId would return a workItem. with signature -

```
def getWorkItem(workItemId: WorkItemId): Future[Option[WorkItem]]
```

Now I am trying to write a function which uses these two to return a seq of WorkItem given a JobId, like this -

```
  def getWorkItemsForJob(jobId: JobId): Future[Seq[Future[Option[WorkItem]]]] = {
val workItemIds: Future[Seq[WorkItemId]] = getWorkItemIds(jobId)

   val res = workItemIds.map {
     idSeq => idSeq.map {
       id => getWorkItem(id)
     }
   }
   res
}
```

The problem is the return type, I don't want to return this monstrous type, instead something simpler like a `Future[Seq[WorkItem]]` should be returned. Now I can flatten it like -

```
  def getWorkItemsForJob(jobId: JobId): Future[Seq[WorkItem]] = {
val workItemIds: Future[Seq[WorkItemId]] = getWorkItemIds(jobId)

  val res = workItemIds.map {
    idSeq => idSeq.flatMap {
      id => getWorkItem(id).get
    }
  }
  res
}
```

which gives me the correct `Future[Seq[WorkItem]]` type that I want, but it requires me to do a get on the future, which does not feel correct. I can also use await but that would be a blocking call. Is there anyway to flatten the above type without blocking ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `Future.traverse`:

```
def getWorkItemsForJob(jobId: JobId): Future[Seq[WorkItem]] =
  getWorkItemIds(jobId).flatMap(Future.traverse(_)(getWorkItem).map(_.flatten))
```

The `.traverse` call takes the `Seq` from the `getWorkItemIds` call and returns a `Future[Seq]` of the results of calling `getWorkItem` on each entry, without the inner `Future` wrapping.

The `.map(_.flatten)` near the end flattens out this inner `Seq[Option[WorkItem]]` to just `Seq[WorkItem]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it the following way:

```
def getWorkItemsForJob(jobId: JobId): Future[Seq[WorkItem]] = 
  for (
    seq <- getWorkItemIds(jobId);
    list <- Future.traverse(seq)(getWorkItem)
  ) yield list.flatten
```